# How to find vertices, edges and faces of a polyhedron analytically?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, geometric-inequalities

I have a polyhedron which is defined by the following system of inequalities:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \geq 0 \\ 
y \geq 0 \\ 
x + y + z \leq 2\\
x + y + 2z \geq 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The task is to find its vertices, edges and faces. Undoubtedly, I can draw a plot and solve it theoretically. The question is - how to do it analytically? In this case I am just feeling lucky because it is easy to draw a plot, but this is clearly not the way for more difficult systems and especially for polytopes, not polyhedra.

Comment: Do you know linear algebra? Geometrically, each one of those constraints defines a plane that describes a face. Pairs of the planes will intersect in lines that describe edges, and the lines will intersect in points that describe the vertices.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Yes, but the planes also intersect in lines that do *not* describe edges, and the lines intersect in planes that do *not* describe vertices.  To actually find the vertices and edges probably requires something resembling. the simplex algorithm.

Comment: @saulspatz Sure, but those are easy to rule out by checking the remaining inequalities. The simplex algorithm purposefully does not enumerate all of the vertices. For the most part, in order to enumerate them all you really do end up doing half-space intersections (though there are cleverer ways to do that).

Comment: @MichaelBiro I agree, but I still think your comment elides difficulties that the OP will encounter if he actually tries to carry out the indicated procedure.  If I had to sit down right now and write a computer program that would take the equations of a set of planes as input, and output the vertices of the polyhedron they determine, I would have some difficulty, I think.  (When I mentioned the simplex algorithm, I just meant some  regular procedure for going from vertex to vertex.)